# Pull api information without refreshing the page

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, xml-parsing

I have a form that will be posted to a PHP method. However before it is posted I want to pull some information from a 3rd party api service that returns an xml and use that xml to populate my `<select>` box.

Mostly I was thinking I would be doing this using JS but it turns out Same Origin policy denies pulling xml from remote apis. So now Im stuck.

I render the HTML form user inputs their api credentials the press the button pull data this should call a JS method that would parse the XML from the API and then populate the `<select>` box on the form and then the user can submit the form it self.

How can I go about this if the API only serves XML and JS has the Same Origin Policy.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make cross domain AJAX calls for XML... There are some work arounds though. Try this out.. 
http://benalman.com/projects/php-simple-proxy/

Answer (score 0):

Please check it out, HTML5 CORS methods

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/